# Verification of solution of a basic problem in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I've to find the set of points in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $z^{n-1}=\bar{z}$ for a fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $z=r\,cis(\theta)$. Then $z^{n-1}=r^{n-1}\,cis\big((n-1)\theta\big)$ and $\bar{z}=r\,cis(-\theta)$. Equationg the two terms, we have
$$r^{n-1}\,cis\big((n-1)\theta\big)=r\,cis(-\theta)$$
For a solution, we have $r=1$ and solve for $\theta$ as $\cos\big((n-1)\theta\big)=\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin\big((n-1)\theta\big)=\sin(-\theta)$. That respectively give us $\theta=\frac{2m\pi}{n-2},\,m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\theta=\frac{2k\pi}{n},\,k \in \mathbb{N}$. We take the common solutions from the two solution sets.

I'm not confident with this solution as think it does not give us all of the solutions. For example, it may not be okay to take $r=1$ in the first place. For even $n$, $r=-1$ works just fine. Are there any other values of $r$ in the solution set? Is there a better method?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For $n=1$ the condition gives $\bar z = 1 \iff z=1\,$.
- For $n=2$ it is $z = \bar z \iff z \in \mathbb{R}\,$.
- For $n \gt 2$ taking the magnitude of the two sides $|z|^{n-1}=|\bar z|=|z| \implies |z| \in \{0,1\}\,$, which gives $z=0$ or otherwise, multiplying by $z \ne 0\,$, the $n^{th}$ roots of  unity, solutions of $z^n=1$.

Answer (score 0):

So we know two basic facts about complex numbers: the conjugate of $ab$, call it $(ab)'$, is the conjugate of $a$ times the conjugate of $b$,  and $z z'= |z|^2$. So we have $(z^{n-1})' = z$, and so $z^{n-1}*(z')^{n-1} = zz'$ shows that |z | = 1. But then we also similarly have $z^n= |z|^2 = 1$, so that $z$ must be an $n$th root of unity.